# Не устанавливается Oracle 19c

Tags: oracle

При установке Oracle 19c на Windows 7, идет установка до 52%,потом стоит и нечего не происходит. Жрет только физическую память в 5Г. Что делать?

Comment: Попробуйте запустить установку от имени администратора, либо использовать более современную ОС.

Comment: ок. большое  спасибо.